# Can I see the different WiFi SSID and their channels with iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, wifi, ssid

I would like to know the way for how to get the SSID of all WiFi hotspot around me and their channels.
I have been researching in the forum and I think I can't if I want upload my App to AppStore  because I had to use a private library.
Is it right or not? :(

Comment: IOS 8.   Does anyone know if Apple's position on SSID discovery has changed.  I've searched the updated docs and I haven't found anything new regarding this subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment you can only see current connected SSID details using the CaptiveNetwork framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) unless you use some private library as you said but this will get rejected. From my research Apple have been restricting access to WIFI services all developers apart from a few like the Boingo, Vodafone or BT app. See this comment from Apple support engineer [here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/801233#801233) about this topic, most of which state to submit a DTS request...